# How to POST with application/x-www-form-urlencoded header and URLSearchParams using isomorphic-fetch

Tags: node.js, curl, fetch-api, isomorphic-fetch-api, http-status-code-411

This is a CURL example which works fine:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url <url> \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer <authorization token>' \
  --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data 'category=1&userId=<uuid>'
```

I'm trying to reproduce this request using [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch).

I've tried this:

```
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
searchParams.set('category', category);
searchParams.set('userId', userId);

return fetch(`<url>`, {      
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization: Bearer <authorization token>',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
  },
  body: searchParams
})`
```

But I get a `411` status code error response ([length required](https://httpstatuses.com/411))

More info about `URLSearchParams` and `Fetch` here:

[fetch documentation](https://github.github.io/fetch)

[fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#body-mixin)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know about isomorphic-fetch, but I do know about the Fetch Standard and it requires the user agent to set the Content-Length header for these kind of requests. (You also don't have to set Content-Type yourself, the user agent should take care of that too.)

Comment: You are right, I guess I was confused because in the CURL request there was no need to specify the `Content-Length` header. May be you can write the comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the server implementation is correct the problem here is with isomorphic-fetch (or much more likely, the underlying GitHub's WHATWG Fetch polyfill) in that it doesn't add the Content-Length header as it's required to for fixed-length bodies by the Fetch Standard.

(You should also be able to omit the Content-Type header as that is also supposed to be inferred from the URLSearchParams object and added by the implementation of the API.)